# Loggin in to VueJS App via Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, vue.js, authentication, spring-security

I am building a webapp with a Spring Backend and a VueJS frontend.
I am trying to secure my app via Spring Security but i noticed some major problems. 
First I tried to secure the app with the standard spring security login mechanism but due to the fact that the vue app runns on a different port than my spring app

```
.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/","/css/**","/login.html","/register.html","/index.html")
                .permitAll().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/application.html","**localhost:8080**").hasAnyRole("USER","ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin_application.html").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                [...]
```

the tomcat is not listening on the vue port (:8080 in this case) so it just can't see if someone is connecting on this port.

I also looked at JWT and OAuth but due to the fact that i have a tight time budget it was too much to implement for me.

Is there a possible way to use the Spring Security mechanism for securing the frontend? If so, do you have any resource I can possible look at?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I setted the forwarding URI to a html document I created in my Spring and attached

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost:8080/" />
```

to it so I have a link to my vue app from my spring security login form.

Just have to close my Vue port via nginx (or so) and then i should be good to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to reimplement this in vue,

doing login with vue, authenticating against my spring security and setting a store variable in vuex store

router.js:

```
beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
                if (store.state.loggedIn == false) {
                    next(false);
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            }
```

main.js:

```
    mutations: {
        loginSuccess(state){
        state.loggedIn = true
        },

    logoutSuccess(state){
        state.loggedIn = false
    }
```

Login method

```
    methods: {
        performLogin() {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.set("username", this.username);
            formData.set("password", this.password);
            Axios.post('http://localhost:8181/perform_login', formData,{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
             .then((result) => {
             this.$store.commit('loginSuccess')
             window.location = '#/dashboard'
             })
             .catch((error) => {
             console.error(error)
             })
        },
```

may this helps one of you!